# is it possible to sign bitcoin transaction on Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, bitcoin

I want to create cross chain transaction without centralise backend. if anyone transfer
WBTC to smart contract with native bitcoin address, smart contract sign native BTC transaction and sent to address.

is it possible from Ethereum smartcontract?

Comment: to sign a transaction you need the private key. If the contract will be signing transactions then you need to upload the private key to the blockchain , which is public. It will work until the first hacker figures out what are you doing there.

Comment: the way everybody does this kind of stuff is sign the message on the client side, and validate the signature on the chain, then if the signature is valid, proceed further to whatever your next step is

Comment: @Nulik what would be the purpose of verifying bitcoin transaction signatures on the ethereum network ?